# ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy android PowerMock JUnit

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, powermock

I am using PowerMock with Mockito for testing a static function as follow. It used to work good until today it is throwing this exception mentioned below.

```
// this test case need to mock static methods so it uses PowerMock
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// this static methods to be mocked are on Environment so that must be 'prepared'
@PrepareForTest({Environment.class, Build.class, Build.VERSION.class})
public class FileUtilityUnitTest {
    //This uses the JUnit TemporaryFolder Rule to create
    // (and discard on completion) a directory for the assertions.
    @Rule
    TemporaryFolder storageDirectory = new TemporaryFolder();
    File nonExistentDirectory;
    File existentDirectory;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Environment.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Build.VERSION.class);
        nonExistentDirectory = Mockito.mock(File.class);
        //so the exists method tends to be false
        when(nonExistentDirectory.exists()).thenReturn(false);
        existentDirectory = storageDirectory.getRoot();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_is_external_storage_writable(){
        when(Environment.getExternalStorageState()).thenReturn(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        assertTrue("External storage mounted ", Environment.getExternalStorageState() == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    }
}
```

And the stacktrace is as follows.

```
    Internal Error occured.
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:150)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:93)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Can anyone share some light on this. I have been googling but cant find a good reference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use maven to run the test for example.. do you get any exception? seems like an idea fault

Comment: i am not sure how to run the test with maven. Can you post any commands that i can try out @MaciejKowalski .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an observation to be noted here. Somewhere i read that its due to the android.jar that gets generated by the build.

Don't know the reason, but i tried to change the compileVersion from 26 to 25 (No significance in 26 or 25. I just changed to another version that was installed with me.) and rebuild the project.

The same test cases started working again without fail.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. I'm not sure what happened, but by updating the `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to match the `support-annotations` version, the issue is gone.

Now the `build.gradle` looks like:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 27
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
}
```

I couldn't find much comments about it, so I hope I can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason that Junit test throws TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy exception is because some of the dependencies is using compileOnly instead of implementation.

For the reason that compiling SDK version matters, is maybe because SDK removed those classes you are mocking.